# How to get the view in a custom list view at a specific position? Android?

Tags: android, listview

Let me explain this-- 
For example - I have a custom list view set up that shows 3 text fields in a group.. I.e. each click able item in that list view will have 3 texts.. so now I want to get the 2nd text view at the 5th index of that listview...How to achieve this?

If a have a basic listview with only one item at each index, then this can be achieved by using getItemAtPosition().
Is this similar in the above case also?

Comment: Lets say you have 1000 items although only 1 - 10 is currently visible in the screen. In that scenario there is no view for 11 - 1000 because your Listview is just reusing some of the views that is already created.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  THe entire point of a listview is that it DOESNT create views for every element in the list-  only the ones on screen.  So if your list is more than trivially long, it probably doesn't have a view for that item.  If you think you need this, you're probably architecting your code wrong for a listview.